# OMNIORB: Read current orb setting

Tags: corba, omniorb

It is possible to use CORBA::ORB_init to set the native codeset for the orb.
But if in an application an orb is retrieved in different configurations the orb is initialized only once.

"-ORBconfigFile config1.cfg"

```
CORBA::ORB_var orb1 = CORBA::ORB_init(orbInitParams.argc(), orbInitParams.argv());
```

"-ORBconfigFile config2.cfg"

```
CORBA::ORB_var orb2 = CORBA::ORB_init(orbInitParams.argc(), orbInitParams.argv());
```

But the thing is that the first one wins. So in a big application where the caller of the second ORB_init does not know of the first caller he will get the orb configured like 1.
This matters if 1. uses

- nativeCharCodeSet = ISO-8859-1
  while 2 uses
- nativeCharCodeSet = UTF-8

Is there a way to read the ORB setting to check if settings are attached successful?

---

**Why this shows up:** I am using Omniorb in a dll (Thats where I initialize it). Now the application has a second component using omniorb which comes first. So I lost my UTF-8 configuration.

Comment: Why are you trying to configure the ORB twice?

Comment: You can add a third argument and give each orb an unique name, than you get two different ORBs with different settings

Comment: I don't think omniORB supports multiple ORBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With omniorb it seems not possible to have to orbs in one process or is it possible to read the configuration.